# Storing JTextField input in a String variable

Tags: java, jtextfield

So I want to store a string value in a variable, the value is given through a JTextField and after a confirm button is clicked, I want it to store what's written in the text field in a string variable.

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
public class Window {

    private JButton confirm;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private JLabel label;


public void drawWindow() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("CountryQuiz");
    ClickChecker click = new ClickChecker();


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(40, 80, 200, 200);
    panel.setBackground(Color.green);


    JTextField t1 = new JTextField("Enter country...");
    t1.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
    window.add(t1);


    JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    confirm.setBounds(50, 50, 95, 30);
    confirm.addActionListener(click);
    window.add(confirm);

    window.setSize(400, 400);
    window.setLayout(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.add(panel);

}
private class ClickChecker implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String answer = textfield.getText();


            System.out.println(answer);



            }
        }
    }
```

Results in the following error:

Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTextField.getText()" because "this.this$0.textfield" is null

Comment: You declare 3 class fields, but you never do anything with them, so they remain `null`. I guess what you want to do: in your `drawWindow` method, replace `JTextField t1 = new JTextField("Enter country...");` with `textfield = new JTextField("Enter country...");`.

Comment: [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Answer (score 0):

Your textfield variable is only declared but never used.

Replace the below

```
JTextField t1 = new JTextField("Enter country...");
t1.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
window.add(t1);
```

With

```
textfield = new JTextField("Enter country...");
textfield.setBounds(50, 100, 200, 30);
window.add(textfield);
```